# How can we integrate custom maps in Android?

Tags: android

How can we integrate custom maps like golf course maps etc in Android Application? What is the procedure? Generally custom maps can be vector based or images.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you cannot do it with Google Maps.

But You can use osmdroid that allows you to have custom map tiles: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/ModularTileProviderArchitecture